# d3.js semi pie chart with arrow and text options

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a d3.js semi-pie chart application and wish to add the option of including an arrow that follows the current progress.

So at least at this svg arrow we can control the color of and the current percentage that has been reached. I think this chart would need to update in real time. There is also a white part of the dial a cropped circle in which the arrow indicator would sit on - again probably have the power to control the colors.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>multibar d3</title>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <style>
            
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>



        <script>

       


        d3.select("body")
            .selectAll('svg')
            .remove();

        const data = [{"label": "Completed", "value": 60}, {"label": "Remaining", "value": 40}];

        const width = 120,
            height = 120,
            radius = 60,
            innerradius = 50;

        var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#046395', '#d62828', '#f77f00', '#fcbf49', '#eae2b7']);

        var arc = d3
            .arc()
            .outerRadius(radius)
            .innerRadius(innerradius);

        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.total = +d.value;
        });

        var pie = d3
            .pie()
  .startAngle(-90 * (Math.PI / 180))
  .endAngle(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
  .padAngle(.02) // some space between slices           
            .sort(null)
            .value(function(d) {
                return d.total;
            });

        var svg = d3
            .select("body")
            .append('svg')
            .attr('width', width)
            .attr('height', height)
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'piechart')
            .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');

        var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');

        var slices = segments
            .selectAll('.arc')
            .data(pie(data))
            .enter()
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'arc');

        slices
            .append('path')
            .attr('d', arc)
            .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            })
            .transition()
            .attrTween('d', function(d) {
                var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle+0.1, d.endAngle);
                return function(t) {
                    d.endAngle = i(t);
                    return arc(d);
                }
            });

        </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
d3.select("body")
  .selectAll('svg')
  .remove();

const data = [{
  "label": "Completed",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "label": "Remaining",
  "value": 40
}];

const width = 120,
  height = 120,
  radius = 60,
  innerradius = 50;

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(['#046395', '#d62828', '#f77f00', '#fcbf49', '#eae2b7']);

var arc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(radius)
  .innerRadius(innerradius);

  
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.total = +d.value;
});

var pie = d3
  .pie()
  .startAngle(-90 * (Math.PI / 180))
  .endAngle(90 * (Math.PI / 180))
  .padAngle(.02) // some space between slices           
  .sort(null)
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.total;
  });

var svg = d3
  .select("body")
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', height)
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'piechart')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');
  
// semicircle generation
var semiArc = d3
  .arc()
  .outerRadius(innerradius-2)
  .innerRadius(innerradius-15)
  .padAngle(.02);
  
svg.append("path")
  .attr('fill','lightgrey')
  .attr('d',semiArc({startAngle:-Math.PI/2,endAngle: Math.PI/2}) )
  
  
var segments = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'segments');


var slices = segments
  .selectAll('.arc')
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', 'arc');

slices
  .append('path')
  .attr('d', arc)
  .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .transition()
  .attrTween('d', function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
    return function(t) {
      d.endAngle = i(t);
      return arc(d);
    }
  });
  
var arrow = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', 'rotate( 0  )')

arrow.append('path')
  .attr('fill', '#ef7e60')
  .attr('d', `M -${innerradius-5},0 -${innerradius-12},-5 -${innerradius-12},5   `) // draw triangle

var text = svg.append('text')
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
  .attr('dy', 0)
  .attr('fill', '#ef7e60')

function update(data) {
  text.text(`${Math.round(data[0].value)} %`) // set % text

  arrow.transition()
    .attr('transform', `rotate( ${(data[0].value * 1.8)}  )`) //rotate to desired qantity ( i put to 60% of 180 deg )
}
update(data);
//M 5,50 97.5,5 97.5,95
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <title>multibar d3</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>





</body>

</html>
```

I added a triangle you can rotate. A percentage text, and a function update you can call everytime you want to update your pie chart

EDIT add semicircle.

Comment: is there a way to disable the animations on the segment tween, so only the arrow moves? I feel it looks a bit odd when the last segment tweens in the middle like that

Comment: remove `  .transition()
  .attrTween('d', function(d) {
    var i = d3.interpolate(d.startAngle + 0.1, d.endAngle);
    return function(t) {
      d.endAngle = i(t);
      return arc(d);
    }
  });`

Comment: how would we add a clipped white circle in the middle - as if it were a car dashboard gauge - semi circle in the middle - thats clipped at the bottom

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do, sorry

Comment: if the background was grey - instead of 60% background also being grey -its got a white semi circle behind it - so it looks more like a car dashboard gauge

Comment: Can you draw me something on paint, or link an image pointing to this "clipped white circle" ?

Comment: Its just a semi-circle on which the arrow would sit on

Comment: I edited my answer with a semicircle